# How I deploy Grafana on Azure WebApp with Docker-compose file?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, grafana

I want to deploy monitoring dashboards using Grafana as web apps using Azure-cloud and share them with my team members.

But I found some problem: 
(1) In Docker-compose, Grafana needs volumes to store data.  
(2) So I made Azure Storage & File share. And mapping path this storage to Webapp.

Storage Mount is as follows.

- name : namename
- mapping path : /var/lib/grafana
- format : AzureFiles

(3) And this is my docker-compose.yml

```
services: 
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports: 
      - 3001:3000
    volumes:
      - namename:/var/lib/grafana
```

(4) After I build it, my webapp was down and shown me the screen below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GQCW.png)

and error log is this.

```
service init failed: migration failed: database is locked
Logging is not enabled for this container.
```

I don't know what is problem, and how to fix it.
Also, I want to attach storage and check its inside.

How I do?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Sorry I checked late. I rewrite the route as you said, and it worked! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mount the Azure File Share to the container, then the path you mount will have the root owner and group. But the image runs with the user `grafana`, so it does not have permission to migrate files.

The solution is that mounts to a new path that does not exist in the image. For example, path `/var/lib/grafana-data`. then it will work well. Then you need to copy the data yourself from the path `/var/lib/grafana` to the path `/var/lib/grafana` top persist them.